# Object references not updating after new object is instantiated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I instantiate a new object after destroying the old one once it hit's a boundary. The object instantiates in the correct location and with the correct behaviors, however one script doesn't update the references to the new object even though I have written it into the script.

Collision Event:

```
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() == projectile)
    {
        Respawn();
        Ammo -= 1;
        SetAmmoCount();
        Destroy(GO);
        UpdateReferences();
    }
}
```

UpdateReferences Method:

```
void UpdateReferences()
{
    projectile = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Damager").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    tran = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Damager").GetComponent<Transform>();
    GO = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Damager");
}
```

Everytime I run the game it doesn't seem to be able to find the new object. However I have used this method of updating object references in other script for the same object and it has worked fine. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Respawn Method:

```
    void Respawn()
{
    GameObject.Instantiate(player, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

    projectile.isKinematic = true;
    isSpawned = true;
}
```

It compiles I used some bad names to reference objects and things. Yes the object I am instantiating is a prefab.

Comment: Post your Respawn(); function  code

Comment: `GameObject.Instantiate(Object, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);` ? That code shouldn't compile. I want to know what you are instantiating and how that object is declared. Is this a prefab? Update your code again.

Comment: I use a public GameObject player to reference the prefab in unity

Comment: Replace your respawn function with what I have below and see if that works

Comment: Also what is `GO` and why are you destroying it. You said it doesn't seem to be able to find the new object. Are you getting error?

Comment: GO is the player game object and player is the prefab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading into `Destroy()` a little more it occurred to me about a problem I had before. When using `Destroy()`, you actually destroy the references to that object as well. Thus creating an issue when trying to create a new copy and move the references to that instead. What you should use is `GameObject.SetActive()` and then the references will all update to the new Object with Instantiate and the reference updates in my question above.

Comment: I thought about that but I didn't know what GO was. Great thing you figured it out yourself.

Comment: Yeah naming things is something I'm not great with. Thanks for the help regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Respawn function with :

```
void Respawn()
{
    GameObject obj = GameObject.Instantiate(player, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    obj.tag = "Damager";
    projectile.isKinematic = true;
    isSpawned = true;
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue, references not updating